# Java Interface Derived From Class?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm working on an Android framework (https://www.github.com/IanSwift/jumper) which takes data model classes and uses reflection to update views when they are created or updated. I use a dynamic proxy factory for this, and I currently have the user enter both the real object and an interface that specifies any state changing methods. My question is, is there a way the code could auto generate an interface from the class? It would look something like this.

```
Class<?> derivedInterface = somehowGetAnInterface(Original.class)
```

Where original is an instance something like:

```
public class Original {
    String someData;

    public void setSomeData(String s) {
        someData = s;
    }

    public String getSomeData() {
        return someData();
    }
}
```

And derived interface gets created either at compile time or run time but looks something like this:

```
public interface OriginalInterface {
    public void setSomeData(String s);
    public String getSomeData();
}
```

Comment: You can probably construct such a thing using reflection, but the original class and the instance provided you won't implement your new interface.

Comment: How about you take a stab at it and come back with any specific problems you're having? That's really more in the spirit of this site.

Comment: You can obviously create an interface at compile time, by using annotation processor, possibly even make the user's classes implement it, but that looks like an overkill. Anyway I think that you are solving the wrong problem. Why do you need that interface in the first place? Can you achieve the same result using AOP?

Answer (score -3):

Eclipse can do this. Select the class name, right click and select Refactor, then select Extract Interface. In the resulting dialog, provide a name for the interface and select the methods to be extracted.
BTW, when I tried this myself, I found an error in your posted code: the reference to someData in getSomeData() should be to a field, not a method.